# Access SQL GROUP BY problem (eg. tbl_Produktion.ID not part of the aggregation-function)

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, grouping

I want to group by two columns, however MS Access won't let me do it.

Here is the code  I wrote:

```
SELECT 
    tbl_Produktion.Datum, tbl_Produktion.Schichtleiter,     
    tbl_Produktion.ProduktionsID, tbl_Produktion.Linie,  
    tbl_Produktion.Schicht, tbl_Produktion.Anzahl_Schichten_P, 
    tbl_Produktion.Schichtteam, tbl_Produktion.Von, tbl_Produktion.Bis, 
    tbl_Produktion.Pause, tbl_Produktion.Kunde, tbl_Produktion.TeileNr, 
    tbl_Produktion.FormNr, tbl_Produktion.LabyNr, 
    SUM(tbl_Produktion.Stueckzahl_Prod), 
    tbl_Produktion.Stueckzahl_Ausschuss, tbl_Produktion.Ausschussgrund, 
    tbl_Produktion.Kommentar, tbl_Produktion.StvSchichtleiter,   
    tbl_Produktion.Von2, tbl_Produktion.Bis2, tbl_Produktion.Pause2, 
    tbl_Produktion.Arbeiter3, tbl_Produktion.Von3, tbl_Produktion.Bis3,   
    tbl_Produktion.Pause3, tbl_Produktion.Arbeiter4, 
    tbl_Produktion.Von4, tbl_Produktion.Bis4, tbl_Produktion.Pause4, 
    tbl_Produktion.Leiharbeiter5, tbl_Produktion.Von5, 
    tbl_Produktion.Bis5, tbl_Produktion.Pause5, 
    tbl_Produktion.Leiharbeiter6, tbl_Produktion.Von6, 
    tbl_Produktion.Bis6, tbl_Produktion.Pause6, tbl_Produktion.Muster
FROM 
    tbl_Personal 
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_Produktion ON tbl_Personal.PersID = tbl_Produktion.Schichtleiter
GROUP BY  
    tbl_Produktion.Datum, tbl_Produktion.Schichtleiter;
```

It works when I group it by all the columns, but not like this.

The error message say that the rest of the columns aren't part of the aggregation-function (translated from german to english as best as I could).

PS.: I also need the sum of "tbl_Produktion.Stueckzahl_Prod" therefore I tried using the SUM function (couldn't try it yet).

Comment: Either the column needs to be aggregated via a formula like `sum` or `max`, etc OR it has to be in the GROUP BY clause. This is a rule in every RDBMS (except pre-5.7 Mysql). Is there a reason why you don't want to include every non-aggregated column in the GROUP BY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something along these lines?

```
SELECT 
    tbl_Produktion.Datum, tbl_Produktion.Schichtleiter,     
    MAX(tbl_Produktion.ProduktionsID), MAX(tbl_Produktion.Linie),  
    MAX(tbl_Produktion.Schicht), MAX(tbl_Produktion.Anzahl_Schichten_P), 
    MAX(tbl_Produktion.Schichtteam), MAX(tbl_Produktion.Von), MAX(tbl_Produktion.Bis), 
    SUM(tbl_Produktion.Stueckzahl_Prod)
FROM
    tbl_Personal 
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_Produktion ON tbl_Personal.PersID = tbl_Produktion.Schichtleiter
GROUP BY  
    tbl_Produktion.Datum, tbl_Produktion.Schichtleiter;
```

I have used the MAX function for all the data except the two items you specify in the GROUP BY and the one where you desire the SUM. I took the liberty of leaving out mush of your data just to get started.

Using the MAX function turns out to be a convenient workaround when the data item is known to be unique within each group.  We cannot know your data or your itent, so we cannot tell you whether MAX will yield the results you need.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the easy and convenient answer.
In this case I used `First(tbl.Produktion.ProduktionsID) etc. ...` as this suited the dataset a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an aggregation function in the `select` clause, you must `group by` every column that you're `select`ing that's not an aggregation.  If you don't want to do that for some reason (perhaps it changes the output of the aggregation in way that you don't intend) you either must think of an aggregate to use (pick a value.  Average? Max? Min?) or just do two selects, one for the aggregate, and one for the non-aggregates.  But, then, you have to decide how to get the non-aggregated fields that make sense for the aggregate (or show them all in a table, I suppose?)